# How can I prevent NSXMLParser from exiting when it hits the copyright symbol?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsxmlparser

I'm trying to use NSXMLParser to deal with an XML document.  However, when a node has ® as an element value, the parser quits by using the parserDidEndDocument delegate method.

How can I prevent parsing from quitting when an ® symbol is encountered?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 3 things:

- Post here xml file example, so other people could test it
- Try to define delegate's method `parser:parseErrorOccurred:` and see are any errors reported
- Try to change file encoding to UTF-8 like that:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  ```

Comment: None of the last two options worked for me.using CDATA for specific symbol ® solved the problem.we can't parse special symbols without CDATA.